# Laravel - How to get Line Manager FullName in a self referencing table

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this model:

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'hr_employees';

   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'employee_code',
              'line_manager_id',
              'employee_designation_id',
              'employee_grade_level_id',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'nationality_id',
              'other_name',
              'is_hod',
              'department_id',
          ];

   public function linemanager()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee','line_manager_id');
   }

   public function designation()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDesignation','employee_designation_id');
   }

   public function gradelevel()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrGradeLevel','employee_grade_level_id');
   }

   public function department()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment','department_id');
   }

   public function fullName()
   {
       return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->other_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
   }  
}
```

Each Employee has a Line Manager (line_manager_id). Line Manager has many employee under, but an employee cannot have more than one Line Manager. A line manager is also an employee

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $employees      =       HrEmployee::all();
    return view('dashboard')
            ->with('employees', $employees);   
}
```

view

```
         @foreach($employees as $key => $employee)
        <!-- Profile Image -->
        <div class="card card-secondary card-outline">
          <div class="card-body box-profile">

            <h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{auth()->user()->first_name}} {{auth()->user()->last_name}}</h3>

            <p class="text-muted text-center">Designation: {{isset($employee->designation) ? $employee->designation->designation_name : 'N/A'}}</p>

            <ul class="list-group list-group-unbordered mb-3">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>Staff ID:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->employee_code) ? $employee->employee_code : 'N/A'}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>Department:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->department) ? $employee->department->dept_name : 'N/A'}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>Grade Level:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->gradelevel) ? $employee->gradelevel->grade_level_name : 'N/A'}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>Line Manager:</b> <a class="float-right"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>


          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        @endforeach
```

The employee table has line_manager_id. So it must take this as a reference point. From the view blade above, how do I display the fullName (first_name, last_name) of the employee's Line Manager?

Thank you.

Comment: `{{ employee->first_name . ' '. employee->last_name` }} or `{{ employee->fullName() }}`

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko - Its like you dont understand. The employee table has line_manager_id. So it must take this as a reference point

Comment: i dont know the structure of your table, but u can get `linemanager` by relation, `{{ $employee->linemanager->first()->linemanagerField }}`, `$employees = HrEmployee::with('linemanager')->all();`